# C# URL Reservation Host issue

Tags: c#, web-services, acl, netsh

I am having this odd issue where i do add Reserve URL to ACL list (programmatically like so) but when a program is executed, i still get the error message "Access Denied".

```
    public void initRest() {
        // Add ACL Service Exception
        addACLServiceException();
        /*
         * initRest will lunch a separate thread that will be responsible for REST service
         */
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            RestServicesImpl services = new RestServicesImpl();
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
            WebServiceHost _serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(services, new Uri("http://localhost:8000/RestService"));
            _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(RestServices), binding, "");
            _serviceHost.Open();
            Console.ReadKey();
            _serviceHost.Close();
        }).Start();            
    }

    private void addACLServiceException() {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/K netsh http add urlacl url = http://+:8000/RestService/ user=%USERNAME%";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Running `netsh http show urlacl` from CMD window (as admin) i can see that the reserved URL is indeed where it supposed to be

```
 Reserved URL            : http://+:8000/RestService/
    User: DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q\Boss
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-990234104-2306344669-2817477651-1001)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh... So it seems like the Thread was executing quicker then ACL exception was added. A simple thread sleep command solved it like so

```
public void initRest() {
    // Add ACL Service Exception
    addACLServiceException();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ... rest of code
```

Comment: Your netsh process is running asynchronously - and "addACLServiceException" is probably exiting before netsh finishes. You can use Process.WaitForExit() to halt until netsh is finished. This may be better than waiting for an arbitrary length of time.